# When was the calculus first part of college curriculum in USA?

Tags: mathematics, education

Or I guess the Colonies, if it happened before 1776?

I know that mathematics tended to be both applied and emphasized things like taking fifth roots. Also, I think long ago high school and college may have meant different things than they do today.

But what I am wondering is just how long it took for The Calculus to become taught regularly -- I assume, for example, that there were people in America who learned about Newton/Leibniz calculus not too long after it was first published.

I am guessing that it may have first been introduced only in very advanced classes. I do not know if graduate school was a thing in, say, the early 19th century but maybe that would be the level at which it was studied or the equivalent level

I also know that many things, not just in math, took a surprisingly long time to catch on. For example, I believe Harvard medical school did not get a microscope until the mid 19th century (as microorganisms were not then widely accepted as causing disease).

Comment: Alan Tucker, "The History of the Undergraduate Program in Mathematics in the United States": *In the early 1800’s, calculus had not yet entered the regular U.S. college curriculum, although a few institutions, e.g., Yale and West Point, offered classes about ‘fluxions.’*

Comment: @njuffa: I sure would enjoy seeing the Yale or West Point text book that taught fluxions. Frigging 1800 and people used that word? I wonder if they taught it that way in England still. Math was very different in 1800.

Comment: It may help to compare with 1700s Britain: N.Guicciardini, [The Development of Newtonian Calculus in Britain 1700-1800 (Cambridge UP, 2003)](https://books.google.ba/books?id=W45xQgAACAAJ): the "algebraic method" of Leibniz and Lagrange was introduced in Britain in early 19th Century by the [Analytical Society of Cambridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Society). Thus, it is hard to believe that US universities of 18th Century used calculus textbooks (if any) different from those using *fluxions*... But I'm not an expert, and an answer must be based on unive.records and libraries.